# What is the purpose of the command "yum list extras"?

Tags: yum

According to the man pages, `yum list extras` performs the following action:

$ yum list extras [glob_exp1] [...]
                  List the packages installed on the system that are not available
                  in any yum repository listed in the config file.

According to another web page, `yum list extras` performs the following:

> Show all packages not available via subscribed channels or
>   repositories i.e show packages installed via other repos:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-centos-fedora-linux-yum-command-howto/

When I run `yum list extras` all the packages come from either base, or updates. Those seem like pretty standard repo locations to me.

```
[root@mongo-test3 ~]# yum list extras |tail
smartmontools.x86_64                    1:5.42-2.el6                @base/6.3   
sos.noarch                              2.2-29.el6                  @base/6.3   
strace.x86_64                           4.5.19-1.11.el6_3.2         @updates/6.3
systemtap-runtime.x86_64                1.7-5.el6_3.1               @updates/6.3
tar.x86_64                              2:1.23-7.el6                @base/6.3   
tcsh.x86_64                             6.17-19.el6_2               @base/6.3   
udev.x86_64                             147-2.42.el6                @updates/6.3
util-linux-ng.x86_64                    2.17.2-12.7.el6_3           @updates/6.3
virt-what.x86_64                        1.11-1.1.el6                @base/6.3   
yum.noarch                              3.2.29-30.el6.centos        @base/6.3
```

I've even tried the following. It still is not clear to me what qualifies as `extras`

```
[root@mongo-test3 ~]# yum list > /tmp/yum_list.txt
[root@mongo-test3 ~]# yum list extras > /tmp/yum_list_extras.txt
```

`$ vimdiff /tmp/yum_list.txt /tmp/yum_list_extras.txt`
[image: ss of vimdiff]

Update #1:

**Version**
CentOS 6.4

```
[root@mongo-test3 tmp]# ls /etc/yum.repos.d/
10gen.repo  centos-base.repo  epel.repo  epel-testing.repo  puppetlabs.repo
[root@mongo-test3 tmp]# uname -a

Linux mongo-test3 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 6 03:10:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run `yum list extras` I get a list of only those packages which aren't installed via RHN Satellite or an established repo:

```
# yum list extras
Loaded plugins: kmod, rhnplugin
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Extra Packages
MQSeriesClient.x86_64                      7.0.1-5                       installed
MQSeriesJava.x86_64                        7.0.1-5                       installed
MQSeriesRuntime.x86_64                     7.0.1-5                       installed
MQSeriesSDK.x86_64                         7.0.1-5                       installed
MQSeriesSamples.x86_64                     7.0.1-5                       installed
ca-cs-cam.noarch                           13.0.10-7                     installed
ca-cs-utils.noarch                         11.2.11350.0-0000             installed
gsk7bas.i386                               7.0-3.18                      installed
gsk7bas64.x86_64                           7.0-3.18                      installed
rhn-org-trusted-ssl-cert.noarch            1.0-2                         installed
```

What flavor / release are you running? I'm in RHEL 5.9.

Comment: I updated the description. It is Cent 6.4, running inside an openstack instance

Comment: It would seem that openstack has changed the behavior of `yum list extras` - running it on RHEL 6.4, I get the behavior exactly as described in the man pages, not the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: I checked another openstack instance and found the same behavior. Even though only base and epel6 were loaded, almost every package showed up as an extra. I tried a bare metal install of cent 6.4, and found the correct behavior you described.